# Django background thread

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I am making a Django app. it needs to do background work (interacting with outside APIs) while the server is running, so it looks to me like I need to start a separate thread independent from all outside requests. What is the best way to go about this?

my first instinct was to simply `import threading` and start another thread, but where would I place that code in the Django app? is that even the right approach? do I need to make an outside service script that communicates with the app?

my googling has only lead me to things like django-background-tasks and celery, though from my understanding those solutions are only for tasks in views that take a long time, for returning the webpage before the task is actually done. do these solutions have support for background threads? I'm not looking for running a function every x amount of time, I want it to run forever from the moment Django starts.

I want it to be preferably self-contained inside the app, so a solution without an outside service script would be ideal. I want the app to be installable via pip.

Comment: Starting a thread from the main app seems like a reasonable approach, especially since you need it to be self-contained. You should be able to use the `AppConfig.ready()` hook to do that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready